# For a linear map $T(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n) = a_1v_1$, why does this automatically imply $Tv_1 = v_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my book, they have a basis $v_1,...,v_n$ of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and they say they can construct the following linear map for $T \in L(V)$:

$T(a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n) = a_1v_1$.

Why can they do this linear map? It seems they just pulled it out of thin air.

Also, why does this linear map imply that $Tv_1 = v_1$?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n\Rightarrow T(x)=a_1v_1$

$y=b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\dots+b_nv_n\Rightarrow T(y)=b_1v_1$

Then $T(x+y)=T(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n+b_1v_1+b_2v_2+\dots+b_nv_n)=T\{(a_1+b_1)v_1+\dots+(a_n+b_n)v_n)\}=(a_1+b_1)v_1=a_1v_1+b_1v_1=T(x)+T(y)$

This shows that $T$ is linear map.

Now If $a_1=1$ we get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What properties must a linear map have and does $T$ have them?

Also, for $T v_1$, simply take $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ for $i\geq 2$.

Comment: So I am guessing the way I should view $T$ is that it represents ALL combinations and must hold for all the coefficients? Meaning if it holds for all combinations, then I can find a case where only the first coefficient is nonzero. So basically we are just looking at the very special case with one non-zero coefficient? Thanks!

Comment: That is correct, yes.  $a_i$ in the definition are arbitrary.